# How to transpose string from a file pointer into table or Array

Tags: php, asterisk

I have a problem transposing a string response fgets() ...

the response is something like this ...

```
Channel              Context              Extension        Prio State   Application  Data                      CallerID        Duration Accountcode PeerAccount BridgedTo           
Agent/2704           outgoing             901261499329974     1 Up      AppQueue     (Outgoing Line)           901261499329974 00:02:28                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
SIP/135-00005571     outgoing             90116567011298     17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 61290371819     00:17:40                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
SIP/140-00005744     outgoing             90116562654777     17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 8884317666      00:00:03                         (None)              
SIP/144-00005741     outgoing             90116563334544     17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 8884317666      00:00:17                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
SIP/pbx-load-balance outgoing                                 1 Up      AppDial      (Outgoing Line)           90116567011298  00:17:40                         SIP/135-00005571    
SIP/200-00005730     outgoing             901161384201116    17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 8884317666      00:01:28                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
```

How can I format it to Table or at least to an Array format...

anyone from here?.. thank you so much!! much appreciated!!!

Comment: You would have to omit the first line and then use preg_split on the whitespace/tabs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php, though some headers have empty values, so you're not going to have much fun here

Comment: that's actually my problem there ...those empty values in a column preventing me to do a preg_split or preg_replace...

Comment: I'd be curious as to what someone would come up with to resolve this issue, anything in my head would be hit and miss, sorry I can't be of further help

Comment: That's fine :-) .. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar a csv file, however, there seem to occur multiple whitespaces. The header line seems to have field names without whitespaces. So let's find the field positions and calculate the field length. Then create a regular expression, which fetches the fields just by their lengths. Finally we trim the fields, removing unneeded whitespaces.

```
$csv = <<< '_END_'
Channel              Context              Extension        Prio State   Application  Data                      CallerID        Duration Accountcode PeerAccount BridgedTo           
Agent/2704           outgoing             901261499329974     1 Up      AppQueue     (Outgoing Line)           901261499329974 00:02:28                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
SIP/135-00005571     outgoing             90116567011298     17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 61290371819     00:17:40                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
SIP/140-00005744     outgoing             90116562654777     17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 8884317666      00:00:03                         (None)              
SIP/144-00005741     outgoing             90116563334544     17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 8884317666      00:00:17                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
SIP/pbx-load-balance outgoing                                 1 Up      AppDial      (Outgoing Line)           90116567011298  00:17:40                         SIP/135-00005571    
SIP/200-00005730     outgoing             901161384201116    17 Up      Dial         SIP/pbx-load-balancer/901 8884317666      00:01:28                         SIP/pbx-load-balance
_END_;

$lines = preg_split('~\r?\n~', $csv);


// word begin/end with no space behind (=word begin only)
preg_match_all('~\b(?>[^\s])~', $lines[0], $pos_fields, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$pos_fields=$pos_fields[0];

$regexp = '';
$pos = $pos_fields[0][1];

// (.{10}) for a field width 10
for($i = 1; $i < count($pos_fields); $i++)
  $regexp .= '(.{' . ($pos_fields[$i][1] - $pos_fields[$i - 1][1]) . '})';

$regexp = "/$regexp(.*)/";
$arr = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++)
{
  preg_match($regexp, $lines[$i], $line);
  array_shift($line);
  array_walk($line, function(&$val, $k)  { $val= $arr[$k] = chop($val); });
  $arr[] = $line;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: This is working just fine... But the last Column (BridgedTo Column) isn't included in the array ...

Comment: Ups, I forgot to enclose the `.*` of the regexp in parenthesis :) Just done by edit. `()` in regexp captures a subpattern.